# Importing matplotlib in Spyder (OSX 10.6)

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, matplotlib, spyder

When importing matplotlib in Spyder I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 27, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar
  File "/Applications/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 34, in <module>
    import matplotlib.collections as collections
  File "/Applications/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/matplotlib/collections.py", line 27, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backend_bases as backend_bases
  File "/Applications/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 56, in <module>
    import matplotlib.textpath as textpath
  File "/Applications/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/matplotlib/textpath.py", line 19, in <module>
    import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
  File "/Applications/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 57, in <module>
    from matplotlib import ft2font
ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/matplotlib/ft2font.so, 2): Symbol not found: _inflateReset2
  Referenced from: /Applications/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/libpng16.16.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
 in /Applications/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/libpng16.16.dylib
```

What can I do? I really don't get it. I run under mac OSX 10.6

Answer (score 2):

(*Spyder dev here*) The problem lies in some changes done by the Matplotlib team some time ago that made for us harder to support Mac OSX 10.6.

To do it, we would need to include our own version of `zlib` in our Mac app, and compile every package against it, something I considered too much work and a potential cause of bugs.

That's why I changed the minimal required version of our app to be *10.7*, as can be seen in our [documentation site](http://pythonhosted.org/spyder/installation.html#the-easy-way).

Comment: Yes I read that but I'd rather not upgrade to Lion because it would slow down most of the things.

Comment: Sorry then, for now there is nothing else we can do to help you :-(

Comment: No problem I'll think about switching to Ubuntu ;-)